# Custom sort within 1 instance of a crystal report group

Tags: sorting, crystal-reports

Using vs2008 crystal reports .net c#

I have a report with multiple nested groups. I'm trying to find a way to do different or custom sort, or specify specific order within 1 instance of the groups printed on report
E.g report grouping as bellow. Report prints 2 lots of the nested groups as shown.

I want to specify the sort order ONLY for the first instance data coming under GroupHeader1

```
GroupHeader1  -------> ONLY want to specify customer order in this point only
  GroupHeader2
    GroupHeader3
    Data
    GroupFooter3
  GroupFooter2
GroupFooter1

GroupHeader1
  GroupHeader2
    GroupHeader3
    Data
    GroupFooter3
  GroupFooter2
GroupFooter1
```

Comment: nuts, my layout of the groups did not come out the way it typed it to show the way its nested

Comment: Enter 2 spaces + Enter to make a line break.